# Spring Security "Connection reset by peer: socket write error" when handling JSF resource request

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, resources

I'm working on a webapp based on Spring, JPA/Hibernate and Primefaces with Annotations config for Spring (no application-context.xml). I have a functional webapp based on XML config, but I want to replicate the same application with no XML config.

I made the changes over the configuration and all seems to be right, but when I deploy the application it's crash with the following message:

```
 ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:283)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    //more error lines ...
```

Really, I don't know why happens, but I think that can be SpringSecurity config, this is my `SecurityContext.java`

```
//imports

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/private/**").access("isAuthenticated()")
                                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                                .and()
                                .formLogin().loginPage("/public/index.xhtml")
                                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
}
```

The implementation of `UserDetailsService` is my `AuthenticationService` class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {
    //loadUserByUsername implementation works fine in the XML based project
}
```

Also, I have a `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

And this is my `WebAppConfiguration` class, see the `SecurityContext` class import

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.web.app")
@Import({ SecurityContext.class })
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jsfViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/");
        bean.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

And int the faces-config.xml I have de Resolver definition

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

This is my configuration, maybe I'm making something wrong. The webapp show the login page (defined as welcome-file in the web.xml) but not work.

Please any help is welcome, here the complete project [on GitHub](https://github.com/ropherpanama/spring-jsf-annotation-based)

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. Is used to enable the Spring MVC module, which could remain in conflict with JSF if you're not so careful about paths. Everything else looks ok.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBiker but doens't work.